# How to change textcolor of switch in Android

Tags: android, switch-statement, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm creating an application which uses Android 4.0.
I'm wondering if it is possible to change the text color of the text in a switch.

I've tried setting the text color, but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no specific code, its just a switch in the layout, which is found by ID. And in the code i set the switch.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You must use `android:switchTextAppearance` attribute, eg:

```
android:switchTextAppearance="@style/SwitchTextAppearance"
```

and in styles:

```
<style name="SwitchTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_switch_color</item>
</style>
```

you can also do it in code, also using above styles:

```
mySwitch.setSwitchTextAppearance(getActivity(), R.style.SwitchTextAppearance);
```

---

...and as for `setTextColor` and `Switch` - this color will be used if your `SwitchTextAppearance` style doesn't provide a `textColor`

you can check it in `Switch` source code in `setSwitchTextAppearance`:

```
    ColorStateList colors;
    int ts;

    colors = appearance.getColorStateList(com.android.internal.R.styleable.
            TextAppearance_textColor);
    if (colors != null) {
        mTextColors = colors;
    } else {
        // If no color set in TextAppearance, default to the view's textColor
        mTextColors = getTextColors();
    }

    ts = appearance.getDimensionPixelSize(com.android.internal.R.styleable.
            TextAppearance_textSize, 0);
    if (ts != 0) {
        if (ts != mTextPaint.getTextSize()) {
            mTextPaint.setTextSize(ts);
            requestLayout();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wonder why couldn't they just make `setTextColor` work normally instead of all this bloat.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to look at the theme which you are using for your application. Because the color of the switch is the responsibility of the theme, afaik. So I would suggest you have a look on how you can change the settings of a theme. Or you could create a custom theme with the new colors.

Answer (score 0):

TextView.setTextColor() takes an int representing the color (eg. 0xFFF5DC49) not the resource id from the xml file. In an activity, you can do something like:

`textView1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor))`

outside of an activity you'll need a Context eg.

`textView1.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor))`

For more refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor%28int%29)

Comment: Hello, first thanks for your response! This isn't the answer that I'm looking for, i got it working for textviews and editTexts. But I need it for a switch and I'm not sure how..

Comment: Actually `setTextColor` is not used for `Switch`, unless the style provided for `android:switchTextAppearance` doesn't define a textColor