# Switch-Button thumb gets skewed?

Tags: android, xml, android-switch

The thumb for my Switch-button seems to get skewed(for on&off state). There were similar problems on github, but those were for people making libraries to support Switch button in API 4.0-

main contains the switch-button, and there is a thumb and track drawable applied to it

This is what is happening:

[image]

This is how its suppose to loook:

[image]

switch_track_on.png

[image]

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb_selector"
    android:track="@drawable/switch_track_selector"
    android:textOn=""
    android:textOff=""/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**switch_thumb_selector.xml**

```
<selector>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb">
</item>
</selector>
```

**switch_track_selector.xml**

```
    <selector>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_track_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_track_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 23):

For **Custom Switch (Like IOS switch)** I tried below Steps:

Create a drawable **track_selector.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <solid android:color="#ca120f" />
            <corners android:radius="25dp" />
            <size android:width="2dp" android:height="18dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <solid android:color="#27170432" />
            <corners android:radius="25dp" />
            <size android:width="2dp" android:height="18dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Create a drawable **thumb_selector.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="100dp" />
            <size android:width="24dp" android:height="25dp" />
            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#0000ffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

In your layout :

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/checkboxAttendanceSelector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_selector"
    app:track="@drawable/track_selector" />
```

[image]

Its working fine for me.

Comment: In the Parent Layout make sure to include **xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"**

Comment: For whatever reason, this doesnt work for me. I think it didnt work for the original poster either. Why the hell they didnt include a circle shape is beyond me. 99% of the time you want a circle, not an oval. Probably soe math nerd thought it would be adequate because a circle is an oval. Like many engineering solutions, its correct, but its not very useful.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same requirement. I checked Android code and found that

1. switch ignores any vertical margin/padding applied to a thumb shape drawable (thus thumb always touch the top and bottom of the track)
2. the width of the thumb is calculated by taking the horizontal paddings + the max width of the on and off texts.

This makes really hard to make a circle thumb.

But if you specify the thumb drawable as a layer drawable for the sole reason to be able to specify padding for the single layer of the drawable, you can get the desired effect.

Thumb selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <!--
        NOTE
        We want a thumb with padding around it inside the track.
        Sadly, a switch draws its track and thumb with the same height ignoring
        any padding of the drawable, so using a shape with padding does not work.
        To overcome, we apply a trick. We create layer list because the
        LayerListDrawable draws itself with taking the top, left, right, bottom
        values into account.
        -->
        <layer-list>
            <item
                android:top="@dimen/switch_thumb_padding"
                android:left="@dimen/switch_thumb_padding"
                android:right="@dimen/switch_thumb_padding"
                android:bottom="@dimen/switch_thumb_padding">
                <!--
                NOTE
                No need to specify size because:
                  - The thumb fills the track in height.
                  - The thumb width is determined from thumb max(on, off) text +
                    text padding + drawable padding.
                -->
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="@color/switch_thumb"/>
                    <!-- NOTE did not work, had to set Switch's thumbTextPadding to the radius -->
                    <!--
                    <padding android:right="@dimen/switch_thumb_radius"
                             android:left="@dimen/switch_thumb_radius"/>
                    -->
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I set the on and off text of switch to empty (actually to "" to prevent warning about empty resource).

track:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="@dimen/switch_track_height"/>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/switch_thumb_radius"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/switch_track_off"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="@dimen/switch_track_height"/>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/switch_thumb_radius"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/switch_track_on"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Switch style:

```
<style name="CustomSwitch">
    <!-- NOTE this way the switch will be as width as required minimally -->
    <item name="android:switchMinWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:track">@drawable/switch_track</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/switch_thumb</item>
    <item name="android:textOff">@string/switch_thumb_off</item>
    <item name="android:textOn">@string/switch_thumb_on</item>
    <!-- NOTE if set to 0dp, the thumb was not visible even with padding
              of the thumb drawable set to -->
    <item name="android:thumbTextPadding">@dimen/switch_thumb_radius</item>-->
    <!--<item name="android:thumbTextPadding">0dp</item>-->
</style>
```

And finally, the dimens:

```
<dimen name="switch_track_height">30dp</dimen>
<dimen name="switch_thumb_radius">15dp</dimen>
<dimen name="switch_thumb_padding">2dp</dimen>
```

So the only 'tricky' thing is to keep height = radius * 2.

Comment: I solved it by setting the textColor to whatever the color of the circle is , and placing the switch in a LinearLayout , check my answer above. But thanks :)

Comment: @summers - If you set the color to white, it will not be circular I guess. It will be in oval shape depending on text length. However zsolt solution is the perfect one.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly! Thanks for that :)

Comment: I needed to add left-right padding of switch_thumb_radius in the track as well. Otherwise the switch overlapped the track ends. After doing this, the oval padding worked for me. I didnt have to set the thumbTextPadding at all.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No clue why this happens but solved it by placing the Switch-button within a linearLayout.
There must be some propery(width) of the thumb that has a "match_parent" of some sort that must've been causing it.

**Edit:** It happens when I remove the default 'ON' and 'OFF' text. So to hide the text i changed its color to white. 
[How to change textcolor of switch in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706874/how-to-change-textcolor-of-switch-in-android)

**main.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.toggle_button);

    Switch sw = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);

            //Both of these need to be used to change the text color to white
            sw.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    sw.setSwitchTextAppearance(this, Color.WHITE);

            //Doing this would skew the circle
            //sw.setTextOn("  ");
    //sw.setTextOff("   ");
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp" >

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb_selector"
        android:track="@drawable/switch_track_selector" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always horizontally stretch the graphic itself (ie, "switch_thumb.png") if you can't use the other answers.

If you use the original software used to design the graphic and re-export it after stretching, it shouldn't cause blurring of the image. You'll have to eye-ball it for your dimensions, but starting at +30% stretching should get you close.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Using **"com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial"**

You can customize the colors according to your needs.
`app:thumbTint="@color/select_stroke" app:trackTint="@color/unselect_stroke"`

```js
             <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
            android:id="@+id/switchBioMetric"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/vwLine"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:thumb="@drawable/switch_ios_selector"
            app:track="@drawable/switch_ios_track"
            app:thumbTint="@color/select_stroke"
            app:trackTint="@color/unselect_stroke"/>
```

**switch_ios_selector.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="false">
    <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        <corners android:radius="100dp" />
        <size android:width="24dp" android:height="25dp" />
        <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#0000ffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
        <solid android:color="@color/select_stroke" />
        <corners android:radius="100dp" />
        <size android:width="24dp" android:height="25dp" />
        <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#0000ffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

**switch_ios_track.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <solid android:color="#28BDA9" />
            <corners android:radius="25dp" />
            <size android:width="2dp" android:height="18dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <solid android:color="#27170432" />
            <corners android:radius="25dp" />
            <size android:width="2dp" android:height="18dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

To Solve this issue follow the given steps.

1. Create thumb_selector.xml in drawable.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item>
      <layer-list>
        <item
            android:top="5dp"
            android:left="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:bottom="5dp">

            <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" 
               android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
                <solid android:color="@color/btnColor" />
                <corners android:radius="100dp" />
                <size android:width="24dp" android:height="25dp" />
                <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#0000ffff" />
              </shape>
           </item>
         </layer-list>
     </item>
   </selector>
   ```
2. Create bg_track.xml in Drawable folder.

   ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/hindi"
         android:state_checked="true" />
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/english"
       android:state_checked="false"/>
    </selector>
   ```
3. In your xml layout use SwitchCompat instead of Switch

   ```
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            app:thumbTextPadding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            app:switchMinWidth="@dimen/_70sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_selector"
            app:track="@drawable/bg_track" />
   ```